# how to print product of field using awk?

Tags: awk

Is it possible to print the product of an entire field using awk?

This is simple in R, but it would be a a hassle to call an R script if it can be done in awk.

Sample input:

```
gene1 0.9
gene2 0.8
gene3 0.4
gene4 0.2
```

Desired output (0.9 x 0.8 x 0.4 x 0.2):

```
0.0567
```

Would it be similar to the `sum` syntax? Like

```
awk '{ sum +=$2 } END { print sum }'
```

but using `mult` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as you can use `+=`, you can use `*=`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { product = 1 } { product *= $2 } END { print product }'
```

Note that I've initialised the variable `product` to 1 in the `BEGIN` block before any records are processed, otherwise it would be 0 so would never change.

It may not be of any concern to you in this case but in general, it's a good policy to not output anything when there's no input. To do that, you could change the `END` block to `{ if (NR) print product }`, so that if the input file is empty, nothing is printed.